# U.S. B visa denied under 214(b) in the past, income improved, European passport may show stronger ties?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, paperwork, esta, italian-citizens

I was planning on going to the U.S. on vacation 5 years ago when I was studying abroad. I applied for a B visa as a foreigner in France, the country I was studying in.
The officer denied stating I could not demonstrate strong ties with France and my income was low, typical 214(b).

Fast forward 5 years, I am still in France, but I have been working here for 3+ years holding a work visa. My income has greatly improved as well.

I will soon recognize my Italian citizenship, so a visa will no longer be required to work and live in France. I have a couple of questions:

- Should I try the ESTA with the Italian passport? I have seen it will probably be denied since I will have to answer "YES" to the denied visa question.
- If applying for the B visa is advisable, should I apply with the Italian or foreign passport?
- I am willing to pursue French naturalization as well. Should I wait the moment I become a French citizen to reapply, to show yet stronger ties?

Answer (score 5):

If I were you, I would try applying for an ESTA with your Italian passport first. The ESTA form will ask about other citizenships, whereby you will fill in the passport number of your foreign passport.

Then, at the question whether you've been denied a visa, answer yes. I think (I'm not sure) it asks about further details, such as when it happened.

If it's denied, you need to apply for a visa, which you can do on your Italian passport. Make sure to bring any all proof of ties to France.

Comment: OK, but since I do not have any assets in France, and I will have recently acquired European citizenship, is it risky enough I should wait more time or French naturalization to apply?

Comment: @gstorto Up to you, but if you can bring proof of your employment (wage slips, notarised employment letter) and proof of any other ties, you should be fine. I'm from Sweden and live in Switzerland for studies, and have never had a problem entering under the VWP (i.e. with an ESTA). The ESTA form doesn't ask for proof of ties, and at the border they don't normally do it as much as some people make it seem like.